# fonts en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, edittext, fuentes

No consigo que se cambie la fuente en mi `text`, esto es lo que tengo en mi `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: selectable_navigation_drawer_example
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  provider: ^5.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: 

flutter_icons:
  android: 'launcher_icon'
  ios: true
  image_path: 'assets/icon/pibedslogopng.png'
  adaptive_icon_background: 'assets/icon/pibedslogopng.png'

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
  
  fonts:
    - family: AndadaPro
      fonts: 
        - asset: assets/fonts/AndadaPro-VariableFont_wght.ttf
  
    - family: Cursiva
      fonts: 
        - asset: assets/fonts/Cursiva.ttf
```

Vi videos de como agregarlo y creo que todo lo estoy haciendo bien. Esta es la parte del codigo en la que quiero agregar el `font`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:selectable_navigation_drawer_example/model/cantoscglist.dart';

class DetailsCG extends StatelessWidget {
  final LetraCG letraCG;

  DetailsCG(this.letraCG);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(50, 55, 205, 1),
        title: Text(letraCG.titleCG),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  letraCG.letraCG,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
```

Aqui es donde no consigo que se refleje en el texto:

```
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Cursiva',
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                  ), 
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

La que quiero agregar en la parte de arriba es la cursiva, y esta no se refleja en el texto de la app.